# Cache:Flush fails after updating from Magento 2.3.4-p2 to 2.3.5-p2

Tags: cache, magento2.3.5, deployment

When deploying the update from Magento 2.3.4-p2 to 2.3.5-p2 the `cache:flush` command does not work.
As error message I get `Class Magento\GoogleShoppingAds\Model\Cache\Type does not exist`.
I checked that and actually this class is removed during the update.
Only possible way to get the deployment to work was to disable all caches, then deploy and after flushing the caches enabling them again.
Did anyone have a similar problem and a better solution?

Comment: Remove cache using command line (rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/*), flush redis cache

Comment: @ChandreshChauhan, it's never a good idea to change anything manually in the vendor folder in my eyes.
This way you completely destroy the logic of composer and this will definitely lead to compatibility issue using an old version of a module...

Comment: be sure to clear any redis system cache after upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when upgrading from 2.3.5-p1 to 2.3.5-p2, even when the deployment included disabling the `Magento_GoogleShoppingAds` module in `config.php`.

In my case the solution was to flush Redis cache right before the deployment.

Comment: damn, I knew it was Redis. Just wanted to google it while waiting on the command output.Update: it worked :)
Thanks.